# error handling in angular 5, catch errors from backend api in frontend

Tags: error-handling, angular5, web-frontend

I need advise for handling errors in front-end of web application. 
When I call a service to `get` the community according to community in web app, I want it to catch an error. For example for catching errors like 404.

There is a service for getting community according to id provided.

```
 getCommunity(id: number) {
        return this.http.get(`${this.api}/communities/` + id + ``);
    }
```

that is called in `events.ts` file

```
 setCommunityBaseUrl() {
        this.listingService.getCommunity(environment.communityId).subscribe((data: any) => {
            this.communityUrl = data.url + `/` + data.domain;
        });
    }
```

The `id` is provided in environment. Let's say there are 20 communities in total. When I provide `id = 1` the events according to `community = 1` appears.

```
export const environment = {
    production: ..,
    version: 'v2',
    apiUrl: '...',
    organization: '...',
    websiteTitle: '...',
    communityId: 1,
    googleMapsApiKey: '...'
};
```

The problem is that when I provide `id = null` all community events are occurring | all events list in the backend is occurring.

Please, help ^^

Answer (score 1):

When you subscribe you subscribe with an `Observer` pattern. So the first function you pass in

```
.subscribe(() => {} );
```

fires when the `Observable` calls `.next(...)`

and after that you can provide another function which will fire whenever the `Observable` calls `.error(...)`

so

```
.subscribe(() => {}, (error) => { handleTheError(error); } );
```

The `this.http.get(...);` returns an `Observable` which will fire the `.error(...)` on http error

We also know that `this.http.get(...)` completes or "errors" and it's not an endless one (a one that never completes). So you can make it a promise and manipulate on it promise like.

```
async getMeSomething(...) { 
   try {
     this.mydata = await this.http.get(...).toPromise();
   }
   catch(error) { 
     handleTheError(error) 
   }
}
```

But what I really recommend is to use [Swagger](https://swagger.io/) for your backend and then generate the API Client class with [NSwagStudio](https://github.com/RSuter/NSwag/releases) so you don't have to write the client manually or adjust it or deal with error catching. I use it all the time and it saves us an enormous amount of time

Comment: Thank you very much for such useful info and answer. I will try the options you gave with front - end part as I am responsible for this. Backend is already fixed, it's also written by others. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using ".subscribe" you can create your own error handler and catch the errors like this, directly on the method.

This is an example on how you can use this:

```html
constructor(
    private _suiteAPIService: SuitesAPIService,
    private _testcaseService: TestcaseService,
    public _tfsApiService: TfsApiService,
    private _notificationService: NotificationService) { }

  errorHandler(error: HttpErrorResponse) {
    return observableThrowError(error.message || "Server Error")
  }

  public something = "something";
  
  GetTestcasesFromSuiteSubscriber(Project, BuildNumber, SuiteId) {
    this._suiteAPIService.GetTestResults(Project, BuildNumber, SuiteId).subscribe(
      data => {
        console.log(data);
        this._testcaseService.ListOfTestcases = data;
        //Notofication service to get data. 
        this._notificationService.TestcasesLoaded();
      },
      error => {
        //Here we write som error 
        return this.something;
      }
    );
  }
```

Comment: Are the services in constructors are self written services (not Angular built in services)? Also, do you mean `Observable.throw(error.message || "Server Error")` by `observableThrowError(error.message || "Server Error")` ? Thank you for answer beforehand